# How to use Ember hooks in selenium?

Tags: selenium, ember.js

Development team is using some `ember` hooks for GUI automation.

By how to use ember hooks in selenium automation in place of `xpath` and `ids`?

Comment: We need more details to help you answer your question. What do you mean by hooks. I would imagine selenium helps you click around and application like a user would.

Comment: @Anuj, provide some sample code and then tell the problem you think you would be facing. It would be much easier then!